# What causes sharp peaks in the spectrum of continuous phase BFSK with Manchester coding

Tags: frequency-spectrum, fsk

I'm currently exploring BFSK and I've stumbled upon a result that I didn't expect. I wonder whether there is an intuitive explanation for it.

The intuition I've had about BFSK so far is that it can be thought of as a sum of two on-off keyed carriers. That appears to be what I see. For my graphs I've used a symbol rate of 40, center frequency of 800, and deviation of 190 Hz. The right spectrum shows only one of the two carriers.

No Manchester coding, non-continuous phase:
[image]

And here's a continuous phase version. While I don't intuitively understand what causes the spectrum to be different, I get a feeling that it has something to do with the two carriers constantly changing their phase offsets, and is probably a topic for another question.
[image]

But it's the Manchester coded version that confuses me. First, here it is with non-continuous phase BFSK:
[image]

Finally, here is the continuous phase version. Notice that there are now sharp peaks at +-10 Hz and all of the odd harmonics, whereas the central peak is now missing.
[image]

What is causing these peaks?

Answer (score 2):

Typically I have seen Manchester encoding done by multiplying the original data stream with a square wave at the same date rate of the signal (so in this case it would have been 40 Hz) such that if a Mark or 1 is sent, we instead send 01, and if a Space or 0 is sent, we instead send 10. If we continue to send Marks, we would get a square wave 010101... at the rate of the data. However, from the graphics shown it looks like it was multiplied with a square wave at 10 Hz. Regardless, I believe that the peaks the OP is seeing are consistent with the upconverted spectrum of that square wave. This is what we would expect to see when the frequency deviation is much larger than the modulation rate as in the OP’s case.

What we see here around the carrier frequency in the first case without Manchester Encoding is essentially  "DC" translated to the carrier frequency offset by the frequency offset $f_\Delta$ of 190 Hz, given the modulation index (frequency deviation divided by the modulation rate) is so high. This point is intuitive when we consider the case of a very high modulation index such that the modulation rate is extremely slow, and comparatively the frequency deviation much higher: we would observe single tones at $f_c+f_\Delta$ and $f_c-f_\Delta$. (when present as they would very slowly turn on and off at each location as they switch between the two).

In the second case, instead of it being DC that is being translated, it is the square wave that has been multiplied with the data.

This is exactly what we would see if we were to continuously send Mark (or "1") as the data, or continuously send Space (or "0").  In the first case if we were to keep sending a Mark, we would have a tone as the OP has shown at 800+190 = 990 Hz. If we were to keep sending a Space, we would instead have a tone at 800-190 = 610 Hz. If we send both, with such a large modulation index, we see both, and both still appear as single tones together with the modulation (each individually a large carrier mdoulation essentially).  Consider in comparison what happens in the second case with the Manchester encoding: if we were to keep sending a Mark, instead of sending a single frequency tone at 990 Hz, it would be an upconverted square wave, as a binary-phase-shift keying modulated signal.

Another way to see this is to consider how On-Off keying at baseband is a BPSK modulated signal added to a DC offset. Thus when an on-off keyed signal is translated to a carrier, we would see both the BPSK modulation as well as the carrier itself (as the DC offset component). This is what we see in the OP’s case for high modulation index as the signal in vicinity of the Mark or Space frequency is itself an On-Off Keyed signal.  In order for this to occur such that we the odd-harmonic spectrum of the Manchester encoding (10 Hz square wave), there must be phase continuity between the resulting On-Off keyed signal appearing at the Mark or Space frequencies individually, and that of the waveform that would be there if there were no On-Off keying (if we were to keep sending Mark or keep sending Space without switching between the two). I predict that it is the OP's latter case of continuous phase modulation that is maintaining this phase continuity, as evidenced by the resulting spectrum.